# How to access SQL Server 2012 on EC2 server from my ASP.NET website published on the same EC2 server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, amazon-ec2, sql-server-2012

My site is not able to establish a connection to the SQL Server 2012 from EC2. My connection string is as follows:

```
Data Source=AMAZONA-2SSRDM3;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI;
```

As you can see I am using Windows Authentication; is there something wrong with this approach I am taking? I am new to Ec2

Please help

**The New Connection string i am using is**

```
 connectionString="Data Source=http://ec2-46-137-228-121.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com/;Initial Catalog=MyDb;User ID=something;Password=something"
```

**More Info :** I just restored a new database on to my Ec2 Machine . My sql server instance was using only Windows Authentication which i changed to Mixed Mode. I created a new Login `something` and made it the Db Owner of the Restored Database as well

Properties of the Login User

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=MyDb;User ID=something;Password=something"
```

Just Had to make this Connection String Data Source as `localhost` it worked fine then

Answer (score 2):

You should authenticate using user name and password, not integrated security. Your connection string should be like this:

```
Data Source=AMAZONA-2SSRDM3;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;User Name=TheUserNameAmazonGaveYou;Password=MyPassword
```

Comment: No, you should use the username and password provided by Amazon.

Comment: Verify that you can connect using Sql Server Management Studio

Comment: oh i cannot connect using the same credentials don't know why

Comment: It only allows me to connect via windows authentication